# Adding local dependency in Zeppelin Helium

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am creating a Zeppelin Helium Visualization and I need to add one local dependency. I am working on Zeppelin 0.8.snapshot version.

I am not able to do it, I have tried adding in the following manner. I tried using "*" for my modules, I also tried providing relative path without success.
My module has to be added locally.

```
  {
      "name": "zeppelin_helium_xxx",
      "description" : "xxx",
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "main": "heliumxxx",
       "author": "",
       "license": "Apache-2.0",
       "dependencies": {
         "mymodule": "*",
         "zeppelin-tabledata": "*",
         "zeppelin-vis": "*"
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Zeppelin doesn't support the relative path in helium json. You need to provide the absolute path for the `artifact` field.

Here is one example from https://github.com/1ambda/zeppelin-highcharts-columnrange/blob/master/zeppelin-highcharts-columnrange.json

```
{
  "type" : "VISUALIZATION",
  "name" : "zeppelin-highcharts-columnrange",
  "version" : "local",
  "description": "Column range chart using highcharts library",
  "artifact" : "/Users/lambda/github/1ambda/zeppelin-highcharts-columnrange",
  "icon": "<i class=\"fa fa-align-center\"></i>"
}
```

Additionally, there is a JIRA ticket for this issue.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2097

And you might see an incorrect error message when you load local helium packages.

```
ERROR [2017-03-05 12:54:14,308] ({qtp1121647253-68} 
HeliumBundleFactory.java[buildBundle]:131) - Can't get module name and version of package zeppelin-markdown-spell
```

Then check the `artifact` value again. Probably, it's invalid.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2212

Comment: Thanks for the response. My issue is different, I have a locally available node modules and I am unable to add it to the package.json. I am specifying  a path for mymodule, weather relative or absolute, it throws an error on enable.  It it possible to add my local modules?

Comment: If it's safe to publish, what about publishing your own module?

Comment: Unfortunately, at this stage it can not be published, for the time being, I created a fat js file and I am able to make progress. Thanks for all the help